# How to sum up the ages?

Tags: java

This is my program

```
package com;        
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

        public class GroupByDemoInJava8 {
            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                try {
                    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(); // Date Format is MM/DD/YYYY
                    personList.add(new Person("Mike", "London", 15, "01/01/1981"));
                    personList.add(new Person("John", "London", 21, "01/02/1981"));
                    personList.add(new Person("Prasanna", "London", 28, "04/28/1990"));
                    personList.add(new Person("Monobo", "Tokyo", 34, "04/28/1990"));
                    personList.add(new Person("Sam", "Paris", 44, "07/12/1992"));
                    personList.add(new Person("Nadal", "Paris", 5, "04/02/1992"));
                    String patternInput = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatInput = new SimpleDateFormat(patternInput);
                    String outputPattern = "MMM-yy";
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
                    Map<String, List<Person>> personByMap = new TreeMap<String, List<Person>>();

                    for (Person p : personList) {
                        int sumAge = 0;
                        Date inputDate = simpleDateFormatInput.parse(p.getDateOfBirth());

                        String outPutDate = simpleDateFormatOutput.format(inputDate);

                        if (!personByMap.containsKey(outPutDate)) {
                            sumAge = sumAge+p.getAge();
                            System.out.println("Date "+outPutDate+" "+"Age "+sumAge);
                        }

                else
                    {
                        personByMap.get(outPutDate).add(p);
                    }       

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You're not adding `Person`s to the `Map` so that `if` condition is always going to be true

Comment: Since your class i named `GroupByDemoInJava8`, maybe you would like to do something like `Map<String, Integer> sums = personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```java
public class GroupByDemoInJava8 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    /* INITIALIZATION */
    Map<String, Integer> result = personList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDateOfBirth,
        Collectors.summingInt(Person::getAge));
  }
}
```

As mentionned [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
try {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(); // Date Format is MM/DD/YYYY
    personList.add(new Person("Mike", "London", 15, "01/01/1981"));
    personList.add(new Person("John", "London", 21, "01/02/1981"));
        personList.add(new Person("Prasanna", "London", 28, "04/28/1990"));
        personList.add(new Person("Monobo", "Tokyo", 34, "04/28/1990"));
        personList.add(new Person("Sam", "Paris", 44, "07/12/1992"));
        personList.add(new Person("Nadal", "Paris", 5, "04/02/1992"));
        String patternInput = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatInput = new SimpleDateFormat(patternInput);
        String outputPattern = "MMM-yy";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
        Map<String, Person> personByMap = new TreeMap<String, Person>();
        Map<String, Person> personByResult = new TreeMap<String, Person>();

        new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person p : personList) {
            int sumAge = 0;
            Date inputDate = simpleDateFormatInput.parse(p.getDateOfBirth());

            String outPutDate = simpleDateFormatOutput.format(inputDate);

            if (personByMap.containsKey(outPutDate)) {
                sumAge = personByMap.get(outPutDate).getAge() + p.getAge();
                personByMap.get(outPutDate).setAge(sumAge);
                personByResult.remove(outPutDate);
                System.out.println("Date " + outPutDate + " " + "Age " + sumAge);
            }

            else {
                // personListTest.add(p);
                // sumAge=p.getAge();
                personByMap.put(outPutDate, p);
                personByResult.put(outPutDate, p);
            }

        }
        // using for-each loop for iteration over Map.entrySet()
        for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : personByResult.entrySet())
            System.out.println("Date " + entry.getKey() + ", Age " + entry.getValue().getAge());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have a GroupedDTO to which i need to set

Comment: all the values are not set know in personByResult

Comment: @user663724  Can you please give other sample data?